# GitLab CI/CD Could I get artifacts real path in runner then send files with scp?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm learning GitLab CI/CD, I want to when finished build send files in artifacts, the idea is possible?

```
image: maven:3.8.1-jdk-11

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "*/target/*.jar"

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - scp -r <artifacts_path> root@test.com:~/Deploy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I get artifacts real path in runner then send files with scp?

Generally speaking, *no*. You must rely on artifact restoration process. Keep in mind that (1) artifacts are generally not stored on the runner and (2) docker runners execute jobs inside of a docker container and typically would not have access to files on the runner host, even if artifacts were stored there.

When jobs start, artifacts from previous stages are restored into the workspace.

So, as an alternative solution, you can simply start with an empty workspace (don't checkout the repo), then upload all files in the workspace, which should be only the restored artifacts, assuming there are no file-based variables.

```yaml
deploy:
  variables:  # prevent checkout of repository
    GIT_STRATEGY: none 
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ls -laht  # list files, which should be just restored artifacts
    - scp -r ./ root@test.com:~/Deploy
```

Another way might be to just use the same glob pattern used in the `artifacts:paths:` to find the files and upload them.

```yaml
variables:
  ARTIFACTS_PATTERN: "*/target/*.jar"

build:
  # ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $ARTIFACTS_PATTERN

deploy:
  script: # something like this. Not sure if scp supports glob patterns
    - rsync -a -m --include="$ARTIFACTS_PATTERN" user@remote:~/Deploy
```

Comment: Thank you sytech, this both solution solve my problem.